# Weird null reference exception when inheriting a Fragment

Tags: android, inheritance, android-fragments

I have an app with different fragments. Each fragment is a calculator. To create the last one (`PointsPlusCalculatorFragment`) I inherited it from another Fragment and I overrode the changed methods. I supposed this way it should work, but I get null reference exceptions when switching views in the `ViewPager`. The source code for the app can be found [here](https://github.com/carlescs/PPCalc/tree/pointsplus).

Why does this happen?

Here is the logcat error:

```
06-03 12:43:34.900      877-877/cat.company.ppcalc E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
        at cat.company.ppcalc.fragments.ProPointsCalculatorFragment.SetUnits(ProPointsCalculatorFragment.java:86)
        at cat.company.ppcalc.fragments.ProPointsCalculatorFragment.onSharedPreferenceChanged(ProPointsCalculatorFragment.java:190)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:475)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:461)
        at cat.company.ppcalc.MainActivity$2.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:111)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:567)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:551)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2015)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at co
06-03 12:43:34.910      877-877/cat.company.ppcalc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cat.company.ppcalc, PID: 877
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at cat.company.ppcalc.fragments.ProPointsCalculatorFragment.SetUnits(ProPointsCalculatorFragment.java:86)
        at cat.company.ppcalc.fragments.ProPointsCalculatorFragment.onSharedPreferenceChanged(ProPointsCalculatorFragment.java:190)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:475)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:461)
        at cat.company.ppcalc.MainActivity$2.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:111)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:567)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:551)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2015)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygo
```

This are the lines that give the error:

```
private void SetUnits(View view) {
    String unit= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString("selected_unit","grams");
    String[] unitsValues=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.unitsValues);
    String[] units=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.units);
    int index= Arrays.asList(unitsValues).indexOf(unit);
    String unitName=units[index];
    -- This line -- TextView carbsView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unitCarbs);
    carbsView.setText(unitName);
    TextView fatView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unitFat);
    fatView.setText(unitName);
    TextView fibreView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unitFibre);
    fibreView.setText(unitName);
    TextView proteinView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unitProtein);
    proteinView.setText(unitName);
    TextView portionView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unitPortion);
    portionView.setText(unitName);
}
```

The two fragments use the same layout file.

Comment: Can you post the lines near `ProPointsCalculatorFragment.java:86`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the inflated `View` is not Null. `(View view)`

`private void SetUnits(View view)`

Make sure that the inflated view is passed as well.

Comment: Thanks. It had nothing to do with inheritance. Just adding a null check fixed the issue. I'm still not used to debugging android apps.

Comment: Welcome, please free to ask any help